# Send keystrokes from android device to PC without "stutter"

Tags: android, tcp

I'm working on an android app that when a button in the app is pressed, sends a key stroke to a server listing on the PC. Everything is working fine expect for a problem of the output "stuttering" when the button is pressed rapidly. If on the client is press rapidly, the server will "stutter" and sometimes simply become unresponsive. The cod I'm using is extremely simple. To simple?

**Server side:**

```
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
        while(true)
         {

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

           keyin = inFromClient.readLine();
              robby.translateAndForward(keyin);
             }

      }
catch (Exception ex)
```

....
On the client

```
public class ImageBoundListener implements OnTouchListener {
private ImageView view;
private static   PadClient client;
```

**The On Touch Event handler**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;;
if (client==null)
{
    client=new PadClient();
}
if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
    client.sender("A");
}

         Integer actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    Log.d(actionCode.toString()," Event occured on: "+view.getTag());


return true;         
         }


    }
```

**The Actual send implementation**

```
    try{
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.104", 6789);
      DataOutputStream outToServer = new     DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
     System.out.println("Writing bytes to the server..");
      outToServer.writeBytes(send);
      clientSocket.close();
}
```

Not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

Your code is opening connection every time button is pressed. If it is pressed rapidly - a lot of connections will be opened simultaneously between client and server.
It would be better to make one persistent connection and send all the data through it.

Also you can add some sort of buffering on the client side. I mean that data from several button presses will be combined into one data packet and sent to the server.

When dealing with communication problems between client and server - network I/O logging (what was sent and what was received on either side) is very important.

You server side can look like this:

```
try {
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    while(true) {         
        keyin = inFromClient.readLine();
        Log.d("SERVER"," received: '" + keyin + "'");
        robby.translateAndForward(keyin);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to take this in a different direction and not re-invent the wheel. Looks like I'm going to use:http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/ (BSD licensed server client, runs on PC and android).